# Some T2 spaces must have a small dense?

Tags: gn.general-topology

If a Hausdorff space $\ X\ $ admits a dense subset $ A \hookrightarrow  X\ $ such that

$$|X|^{|A|}\ =\ |X|$$

then indeed $$|X| \leq |\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)|  \leq |X|^{|A|}\ = \ |X|.$$

It is the case of $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus, if there is a  small  enough dense subspace, there are  not so many endomorphisms.

> Is the converse true?

Namely, suppose $|\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)|  = \ |X|.$ Is it true that there exists a dense subset $A$ such that $|X|^{|A|}\ =\ |X|$?

---

This question generated some attention on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533941/some-t2-spaces-must-have-a-small-dense), but it did not receive any answer, thus I am reposting it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Is the converse true?**

No.

The paper *[Constructions and Applications of Rigid Spaces, I](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90006-3)*, Advances in Mathematics 29 (1978), 89-130, by Kannan and Rajagopalan, describes a countaby infinite Hausdorff space $X$ such that the only continuous maps $f\colon X\to X$ are the constant maps and the identity map. Such a space satisfies 
$|\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)| = \omega  = \ |X|.$

If $A\subseteq X$ is a subset such that $|X|^{|A|}=|X|=\omega$, then $A$ is forced to be finite, and therefore $A$ cannot be dense.